# Managing database connections for unit tests

Tags: java

I have a series of unit test classes that use various connections to a database. Every test class uses two methods with the JUnit annotations BeforeClass and AfterClass to start and stop the database connections like so:

```
public class AccountTest
{
    private static DatabaseConnection _adminConnection;
    private static DatabaseConnection _salesUserConnection;
    private static DatabaseConnection _salesManagerConnection;
    private static DatabaseConnection _financeUserConnection;


    private static DatabaseHelper _helper;

    private static ArrayList<DatabaseConnection> _connections = new ArrayList<>();

    @BeforeClass
    public static void CreateTestEnvironment()
    {
        _helper = new DatabaseHelper();

        _adminConnection = _helper.DoLogin(SessionType.Administrator);
        _salesUserConnection = _helper.DoLogin(SessionType.SalesUser);
        _salesManagerConnection = _helper.DoLogin(SessionType.SalesManager);
        _financeUserConnection = _helper.DoLogin(SessionType.FinanceUser);

        _connections.add(_adminConnection);
        _connections.add(_salesUserConnection);
        _connections.add(_salesManagerConnection);
        _connections.add(_financeUserConnection);
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void DestroyTestEnvironment()
    {
        for(DatabaseConnection connection: _connections)
        {
            _helper.DoLogout(connection);
        }
    }
}
```

I would then pass the connection to my helper object in a test like this for example:

```
@Test
public void AdministratorCanCreateAccount()
{
    Account account = new Account();
    account = _helper.CreateObject(account, _adminConnection);

    Assert.assertNotNull(account.getId());
}
```

The login/logout process in CreateTesEnvironment and DestroyTestEnvironment is duplicated throughout many different test classes, with some classes having more connections than others.

How could I manage the connections in a better way so that I'm not just copying and pasting the same BeforeClass and AfterClass code every time but keep them easily accessible to the unit tests?

Comment: Is your intention really doing *unit testing* or do you do *integration testing* using a 'JUnit'

Comment: Yes, you're correct it's more integration testing using JUnit in this instance.

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried to move this logic to the helper itself ? It can receive a varargs of `SessionType` to connect and keep them until you tell him to destroy them. It can maintains a `Map<SessionType, DatabaseConnection>` to give access to them.

```
/* WARN; This is not production ready. Validation and exceptions handling 
 * is missing and the "destroy" method can be improved.
 */
public class DatabasesHelper {
  private final Map<SessionType, DatabaseConnection> connections = new HashMap<>();

  public void prepare(SessionType... sessions) {
    for(SessionType session : sessions) {
      connections.put(session, this.DoLogin(session));
    }    
  }

  public void destroy() {
    for(SessionType session : sessions) {
      this.DoLogout(connections.get(session));
    }    
    sessions.clear();
  }

}
```

Please note that your methods names does not follow the Java, naming conventions. You should use *lowerCamelCase* for them.